# Which assault rifle does the most damage per second?

Tags: mass-effect-3

As an engineer with overload and incinerate I am looking to find the fastest way to drop an opponent after I remove their defenses. As I only carry one weapon to allow my powers to recharge faster, I find I need an all purpose long/meduim/close range weapon to augment my power usage. Enter the assault rifle. Excluding mods, which of the assault rifles has the most stopping power against health-only (unshielded and unarmored) targets at various ranges?

Comment: M99 rifle is like an assault rifle .50cal... But it has a seriously small magazine. 13~ rounds?

Comment: I'm using a pistol with a scope for my engineer, that is pretty much an all-purpose weapon. With the scope you can fire very far, probably much further than with most assault rifles. I'm using a heavily upgraded M-3 Predator with a backup SMG. Pistols are also good against armor, and for shields you have Overload.

Comment: The Incisor is actually pretty good at most ranges, it's a good single weapon if you snipe a lot. Better for infiltrators than Engineers though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I took screen-caps of the assault rifle profiles from the wiki and measured the rate of fire bars and the damage bars.  I multiplied the pixel values and this is the resulting rankings of the assault rifles:

1. **Revenant (3000)**
2. Particle Rifle (2540)(non-multi-player)
3. Geth Assault Rifle (2322)
4. Collector Rifle (2170)(multi-player only)
5. Vindicator (2135)(Damage has since been reduced in recent multi-player balance patches)
6. Phaeston (1932)
7. N7 Valkyrie (1705)
8. Chakram Launcher (1600)(non-multi-player)
9. Avenger (1500)
10. Argus (1444)(non-multi-player)
11. Falcon (1216)
12. Sabre (912)
13. Mattock (864)(Damage has since been upped in recent multi-player balance patches)

The values are the product of the pixel measurements of the relative bar lengths; they are not the actual damage values from the game.  They should be proportional to the actual game values.

This leaves out the effect of accuracy or any weapon special properties, but if all you care about is damage over time, her you go.

Comment: good to see confirmation on the revenant

Comment: Wow, they went a bit overboard in nerfing the Mattock

Comment: @BenBrocka The semi-auto rifles tend to suffer in this ranking.  I think their lower RoF is probably more than compensated for by their accuracy or other unique abilities.

Comment: I appreciate the research but I'm looking for the real numbers (or the real highest dps rifle). If the rate of fire and damage bars do not provide accurate or complete information they aren't of much use and it is a little fruitless to use them in ranking the weapons.

Comment: @Bravo840.  If the values are consistent and proportional to the actual values(which I think is a reasonable assumption), then the rankings would be the same regardless.  If you want more accurate numbers than this, you are more than welcome to do the research yourself and update this answer.

Comment: @CaulynDarr the "values have no in game relevance" threw me off. It all makes sense now. Thanks.

Comment: Are these measurements of all the base values? Do any of these values significantly change in comparing the I vs. X models, or do they remain proportional?

Comment: These are all off of the level one guns. I'm not sure if the upgrades are proportional; that is a good question.  My guess would be that they are.  I've never seen a gun go from having less damage than another when both are level 1 and then have more when both are level 5.

Comment: I think you forgot about Capacity? Geth Assault Rifle has a magazine of 80 rounds. Then again, maybe I'm just biased cause I love the Geth :3

Comment: @Aceofgods That's intentional. The question was specifically about DPS, so I disregarded all other aspects like weight, capacity, and accuracy.

Comment: Mattock was a beast during the demo, such a shame what they did to it.

Answer (score 5):

The Mattock (435) if you can click fast enough, and the Revenant (424) if you can deal with the inaccuracy, top the DPS for for assault rifles. The next best is the Vindicator at 380.
[Source](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmDvzCRwli77dFA1cWZjS0lQOWZxSmVsVXpjd0RLYUE#gid=0)

Answer (score 1):

I actually prefer the raptor sniper rifle to any normal assault rifle, its got bonus armor damage and has a pretty good rate of fire and its weight is decent.  As for the fastest rate of fire assault rifle , you can't beat the Revenant in terms of bullets per second.  Its just not that accurate at range but up close it puts out a huge amount of bullets and damage.

Answer (score 1):

For sheer power and accuracy, it has to be the M-99 Sabre. Its downside is rate of fire and capacity. I can kill most targets with one headshot. I actually use it instead of most sniper rifles.

To an above comment, the fastest-firing assault rifle is not the Revenant, it's the Geth Pulse Rifle. It's also more accurate than the Revenant.

Answer (score -1):

the falcon is the most damaging, with the m55 argus a close second in sigle player me3

Answer (score -2):

Cerberus Harrier w/AP and Assault Rifle V and
Recoil reducer as a mod